# Chrome App bluetooth

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a chrome app that displays when a certain Bluetooth device is sending data. specifically, I have 2 bluetooth mice and I want to identify which one is being moved at a specific time. 
I followed the Chrome dev doc and was successful until I tried to implement adding a listener on receive to view the data coming from the device. I am getting a "Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined" error.

This is when I started getting this error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joQaO.png)

Here's the code I'm working with

```js
chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
  for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    //Displaying device names
    console.log(i+": "+devices[i].name);
  }
  //uuid for a specific device
  var uuid = "00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
  // var uuid = devices[4].uuid;
  
    var onConnectedCallback = function() {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log("Connection failed: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
        // Profile implementation here.
      }
    };


    chrome.bluetoothSocket.create(function(createInfo) {
      chrome.bluetoothSocket.connect(createInfo.socketId,
        devices[4].address, uuid, onConnectedCallback);
      console.log(createInfo);
      chrome.bluetoothSocket.onRecieve.addListener(function(receiveInfo) {
          if (receiveInfo.socketId != socketId)
            return;
        console.log(receiveInfo);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked out this [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth) and managed to see a similar code snippet:

```
chrome.bluetoothSocket.onRecieve.addListener(function(receiveInfo) {
  if (receiveInfo.socketId != socketId)
    return;
  // receiveInfo.data is an ArrayBuffer.
});
```

If you look at it carefully, it seems there was a typo in the sample at the `onRecieve` part. It should be `onReceive`. You can see a correct sample [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothSocket#event-onReceive).

***I** before **E**, **except after C***.